# VBA Excel ... How to leave latest 5 backups and delete rest?

Tags: vba, excel

- I want to leave the latest 7 backups and delete the rest ...
  & I want to keep the first backup of each Month ... 
  & The programm should OpenAsReadOnly the backups without asking!

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Workbook_Open()

    If Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Backup", vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Backup")
    End If

    Dim Pfad As String
    Dim Datumzeitstempel As String
    Dim Jetzt As Date
    Jetzt = Now()
    Pfad = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Backup"
    Datumzeitstempel = Year(Date) & Format(Month(Date), "00") & Format(Day(Date), "00")
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs (Pfad & "\" & Datumzeitstempel & ".xlsm")
    ReadOnlyRecommended = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve problem with backup rotation you can do following. Instead of writing files with month and day in it, use `WEEKDAY` function. Then you will overwrite daily backup every time you open your file leaving backups for last week / 7 days.
To solve monthly backup problem You can do same just by using month only. When new month comes the new backup will be started.
Only problem with this solution is that last backup will be overwritten every time you open your file.
If you really need first backup made, then you will have to check for file existence.

But maybe better solution will be to write a script external to your file and run backup on scheduled basis E.g. at midnight. It can even be vbscript you are familiar with.

Comment: they want it with the date :(

Comment: It is not that bad. Just write code that will delete files older than week ago. you can use [This script](https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/719-delete-files-older-than-max-age-in-days) as a nice starting point. Then you have to convince your users that monthly backups will have slightly different names.

Comment: is there a possibility to set max backups on 7 and not max Age on 3 days or else

Comment: You would have to modify the script to sort files by date and then count them until you hit 5. Then start deleting. So yes, it is possible, it just requires some programming. But maybe go talk to your users if they can give up some of their requirements. You will be surprised how often it is best solution.